# How do I use locate to find hidden files in Terminal?

Tags: hidden-files, locate

I am trying to find a hidden file that I know the name, but no the location of.
The name is "message", and I have tried `sudo locate *message*`, but I have not found it. I have too much output, plus I do not think locate is showing the hidden files. Any ideas?

Comment: `ls -la`  (-a shows all files [inc. hidden], l is just for long) ... to find a known.filename, `find / -name wantedfile`

Comment: If the name of the file is "message", then it is not hidden. Hidden files have a dot at the start, i.e. ".message". Do you mean that the filename *contains* "message"?

Comment: When you say you haven't found it, what do you mean? Did `locate` not find it? Did `locate` give you too much output to go through?

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo find / -name  "*message*"` and wait for it to finish? There will be less output if you remove the wild-cards, `sudo find / -name  "message"` which will find the file, if you are sure that the name is message.

Comment: The proper way to call `locate` is (with quotes!) `locate "*message*"`. By the way, `locate message` (with no wildcards, and hence no quotes) is enough. Now if `locate` can't find it, it could be because that file is too recent to be in the database. In this case, updating the database with the command `sudo updatedb` will help (this command will take some time).

Comment: Are you sure you need quotes to call `locate`? I just use the asterisk and it seems to work.

Comment: The question referred specifically to the `locate` command. There is a difference in the commands: `locate` can be significantly faster than `find`, so is there a way to `locate` hidden files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo find / -name ".message"
```

I'm assuming the `locate` command gave you too much info to go through, so this should be a bit more succinct, where it only matches the filename, not the path.

Comment: p.s. I wrote a comment under your question to ask for clarification. This answer may change based on your reply.

Comment: Thank you, but will this command find a hidden file?

Comment: I think it depends what you mean by hidden. The linux way to hide a file is to let its name start with a dot. (It means that some tools will not see it, for example `ls` (unless you use the option `-a`). Please explain what *you* mean by 'hidden'.

Comment: When I say hidden, I am quoting a readme for a practice image for the CyberPatriot competition. The last time the readme said hidden, it was a filename with a dot in it, so I would assume the same for this one.

Comment: The question referred specifically to the `locate` command. There is a difference in the commands: `locate` can be significantly faster than `find`, so is there a way to `locate` hidden files?

Comment: @iND This question was vague, hence why the answers and comments are messy. Please ask a new question, and include what you've already tried. Send me a link and I'll try answering it myself.